# how make JavaScript .load work without window.location.reload()

Tags: javascript, jquery, vxworks

I'm trying to poll, using .load, a specific element id from the server, but the element only is updated if I follow the .load with window.location.reload().

Specifically, the element is a vxworks windmark element* that the vxworks server updates once per second, and the browser should read and display.

the element on the page:

```
<span id="general_response_windmark_id" >$%general_response_windmark#$</span>
```

At end of page I do:

```
setInternval( 'foo()', 1000 )    // to re-display once a second
```

DOES NOT WORK:...

```
function foo()
{
    windmark_field_id = 'general_response_windmark_id'
    $('#' + windmark_field_id).load(' #' + windmark_field_id);
}
```

WORKS:...

```
function foo()
{
    windmark_field_id = 'general_response_windmark_id'
    $('#' + windmark_field_id).load(' #' + windmark_field_id);
    window.location.reload()
}
```

- - the vxworks server replaces "$%general_response_windmark#$" with a changing number string.

thanks

Comment: Could you please share what you add into your code? I am also trying to get info updates periodically without refreshing all page in vxworks webserver. Regards

Answer (score 1):

Place your `<span>` tag in a separate HTML document (all by itself, if you like), and load that using jQuery instead:

```
function foo() {
    var wfid = 'general_response_windmark_id';
    $('#' + wfid).load('external-span-page.html #' + wfid);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
 $('#' + windmark_field_id).load(' #' + windmark_field_id);
```

statement has error.

because within `.load()` first parameter is an url, and as much I know an url can't start with `#` sign.

Recheck on you url assignation to `.load()`, this will fix you problem.

[Read about .load()](http://api.jquery.com/load)

Answer (score 0):

THE ANSWER:
  add the completion function argument to the .load, just after the URL.

THE PROBLEM:
  My original code was doing the .load and then immediately reading the element from the browser page DOM, even though the .load was not done yet.
Using the .load's completion function waits until it is done.

hacha!